# Verifying Authentication with openSSL

Tags: openssl, authenticity

bob has created a private key with

```
openssl genrsa -out Private.pem 1024
```

then created the public key with

```
openssl rsa -in Private.pem -out Public.pem -outform PEM -pubout
```

he created a file named data.txt with "hello" plain text inside and ran the command

```
openssl dgst -sha1 -sign Private.pem data.txt| openssl enc -base64 -A > signature.txt
```

now he sent alice the file `data.txt`. The `signature.txt` and `Public.pem` files.

how can alice verify the authenticity?

thks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to decode your base64-encoded signature and then just verify the signature:

```
openssl enc -d -A -base64 -in signature.txt -out signature.sha1
openssl dgst -sha1 -verify Public.pem -signature signature.sha1 data.txt
```