# Verifying JWT (RS256) using OpenSSL

Tags: openssl, jwt, base64, jwt.io

My requirement is verifying a JWT using public key (RS256). The check should be based on native OpenSSL only.

I use [JWT.IO](https://jwt.io/#debugger-io?token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWUsImlhdCI6MTUxNjIzOTAyMn0.POstGetfAytaZS82wHcjoTyoqhMyxXiWdR7Nn7A29DNSl0EiXLdwJ6xC6AfgZWF1bOsS_TuYI3OG85AmiExREkrS6tDfTQ2B3WXlrr-wp5AokiRbz3_oB4OxG-W9KcEEbDRcZc0nH3L7LzYptiy1PtAylQGxHTWZXtGz4ht0bAecBgmpdgXMguEIcoqPJ1n3pIWk_dUZegpqx0Lka21H6XxUTxiy8OcaarA8zdnPUnV6AmNP3ecFawIFYdvJB_cm-GvpCSbr8G8y_Mllj8f4x9nBH8pQux89_6gUY618iYv7tuPWBFfEbLxtF2pZS6YC1aSfLQxeNe8djT9YjpvRZA&publicKey=-----BEGIN%20PUBLIC%20KEY-----%0AMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAnzyis1ZjfNB0bBgKFMSv%0AvkTtwlvBsaJq7S5wA%2BkzeVOVpVWwkWdVha4s38XM%2Fpa%2Fyr47av7%2Bz3VTmvDRyAHc%0AaT92whREFpLv9cj5lTeJSibyr%2FMrm%2FYtjCZVWgaOYIhwrXwKLqPr%2F11inWsAkfIy%0AtvHWTxZYEcXLgAXFuUuaS3uF9gEiNQwzGTU1v0FqkqTBr4B8nW3HCN47XUu0t8Y0%0Ae%2Blf4s4OxQawWD79J9%2F5d3Ry0vbV3Am1FtGJiJvOwRsIfVChDpYStTcHTCMqtvWb%0AV6L11BWkpzGXSW4Hv43qa%2BGSYOD2QU68Mb59oSk2OB%2BBtOLpJofmbGEGgvmwyCI9%0AMwIDAQAB%0A-----END%20PUBLIC%20KEY-----) initial content for testing. This token was generated:

> eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWUsImlhdCI6MTUxNjIzOTAyMn0.POstGetfAytaZS82wHcjoTyoqhMyxXiWdR7Nn7A29DNSl0EiXLdwJ6xC6AfgZWF1bOsS_TuYI3OG85AmiExREkrS6tDfTQ2B3WXlrr-wp5AokiRbz3_oB4OxG-W9KcEEbDRcZc0nH3L7LzYptiy1PtAylQGxHTWZXtGz4ht0bAecBgmpdgXMguEIcoqPJ1n3pIWk_dUZegpqx0Lka21H6XxUTxiy8OcaarA8zdnPUnV6AmNP3ecFawIFYdvJB_cm-GvpCSbr8G8y_Mllj8f4x9nBH8pQux89_6gUY618iYv7tuPWBFfEbLxtF2pZS6YC1aSfLQxeNe8djT9YjpvRZA

When I enter  Header + Payload + Signature (items 1 and 2 in the picture below) with points between them. Next, I enter a Public key (item 3 in the picture).
[As result I see message ‘Signature verified’ (item 4 in the picture).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zI7l3.png)

**Now I want to get same result using OpenSSL.**

I have performed steps:

1. Create text file /tmp/pub.pem and past below content into it (copied from JWT.IO test case):

> -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----- MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAnzyis1ZjfNB0bBgKFMSv
> vkTtwlvBsaJq7S5wA+kzeVOVpVWwkWdVha4s38XM/pa/yr47av7+z3VTmvDRyAHc
> aT92whREFpLv9cj5lTeJSibyr/Mrm/YtjCZVWgaOYIhwrXwKLqPr/11inWsAkfIy
> tvHWTxZYEcXLgAXFuUuaS3uF9gEiNQwzGTU1v0FqkqTBr4B8nW3HCN47XUu0t8Y0
> e+lf4s4OxQawWD79J9/5d3Ry0vbV3Am1FtGJiJvOwRsIfVChDpYStTcHTCMqtvWb
> V6L11BWkpzGXSW4Hv43qa+GSYOD2QU68Mb59oSk2OB+BtOLpJofmbGEGgvmwyCI9
> MwIDAQAB
> -----END PUBLIC KEY-----

2. Create text file data /tmp/data.txt and past below content into it. This is Header and Payload separated by point (item 1 from picture) :

> eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWUsImlhdCI6MTUxNjIzOTAyMn0

3. Create text file data /tmp/signature.txt and past below content into it (this is item 2 from picture):

> POstGetfAytaZS82wHcjoTyoqhMyxXiWdR7Nn7A29DNSl0EiXLdwJ6xC6AfgZWF1bOsS_TuYI3OG85AmiExREkrS6tDfTQ2B3WXlrr-wp5AokiRbz3_oB4OxG-W9KcEEbDRcZc0nH3L7LzYptiy1PtAylQGxHTWZXtGz4ht0bAecBgmpdgXMguEIcoqPJ1n3pIWk_dUZegpqx0Lka21H6XxUTxiy8OcaarA8zdnPUnV6AmNP3ecFawIFYdvJB_cm-GvpCSbr8G8y_Mllj8f4x9nBH8pQux89_6gUY618iYv7tuPWBFfEbLxtF2pZS6YC1aSfLQxeNe8djT9YjpvRZA

4. I run OpenSSL command:

   ```
   openssl dgst -verify /tmp/pub.pem -keyform PEM -sha256 -signature /tmp/signature.txt -binary /tmp/data.txt
   ```

   But get result:

   > Verification Failure.

What exactly am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of a JWT is base64url encoded and needs to be decoded first.
The [suggested duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14016270/verifying-authentication-with-openssl) only deals with a base64 encoded signature and openssl seems not to be working with base64url encoding.

If you're working on a Windows system, you can decode the signature file with certutil, which can directly decode bas64url:

```
certutil -decode signature.txt signature.sha256
```

Then use the signature.sha256 as input for openssl:

```
openssl.exe dgst -sha256 -verify pubkey.pem -signature signature.sha256 data.txt
```

Then you should get the result:

> Verified OK

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. 
This command `certutil -decode signature.txt signature.sha256` created new file **signature.sha256** wich have length 256 Bytes. It is OK.
But verification command `openssl.exe dgst -sha256 -verify pubkey.pem -signature signature.sha256 data.txt` returns result **Verification Failure**

Comment: yes, openssl can't decode base64url, that's why I wrote my answer. Please check again that your files are ok. I checked it before I wrote the answer and i just checked it again, and got Verified OK. I used all the data from your question. Esp. the public key file should be in the correct format with linebreaks after 64 character and header and footer in separate lines.

Comment: And also I have tried to run command `openssl enc -d -A -base64 -in signature.txt -out signature.sha1`, as result the file **signature.sha1** was created. But this file has legth 0 Bytes (it seems that invalid file).
And when I run verification command it returns **Error reading signature file signature.sha1**

Comment: you posted that comment already before. Yes, i also saw that the result is 0 bytes and of course there will be an error (becaue the file is empty!). Kindly read my comment above again. I actually tested the commands before I wrote the answer and it really works. Maybe there's a little copy/paste mistake in one of the files, a character missing  or something else?

Comment: Yes, thank You very much! I have deleted all earlier files and have repeated all steps. I don't know why it was failed last time, but now your answer about command `certutil -decode signature.txt signature.sha256` resolved the problem. Verification successfull. Thank You once again!

Comment: ah, thanks for the feedback, glad to hear it works for you!  Don't worry, there's always something that can go wrong. Would you mind clicking on the checkmark left of the answer to mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 2):

I found this [gist](https://gist.github.com/rolandyoung/176dd310a6948e094be6#file-verifytoken-sh-L37) quite useful in going from a starting JWT to breaking it into parts, decoding certain bits, and then verifying the payload against the signature.  It uses openssl and perl which should come with most Bash implementations.

I'll paste my 'short' version of the same thing.  In my case I'm verifying a JWT from Auth0.

```bash
# The JWT itself
jwt=eyJ...

# Get Auth0's public certificate
curl https://your_auth0_domain/pem > auth0publiccert.pem

# Extract the public key from the public certificate
openssl x509 -pubkey -noout -in auth0publiccert.pem > auth0publickey.pem

# Extract the input payload
input=${jwt%.*}
echo -n $input > payload.txt

# Extract the signature portion
encSig=${jwt##*.}

# Decode the signature
echo -n $encSig | perl -ne 'tr|-_|+/|; print "$1\n" while length>76 and s/(.{0,76})//; $_ .= ("", "", "==", "=")[length($_) % 4]; print' | openssl enc -base64 -d > signature.dat

# Finally, verify
openssl dgst -sha256 -verify auth0publickey.pem -signature signature.dat payload.txt
#Output should be "Verified OK"
```